# Validate breeze complex-type without validate the entire entity

Tags: javascript, breeze

When you want to validate breeze-entity you write:

```
     this.entityAspect.validateEntity()
```

But what about if I want to fire validations only for complex-type, without fire the entire-entity validations?

complexType.complexAspect not have method validateEntity.

So, what should I do?

---

**Edit after I saw Jay answer:**

I tried to use method validateProperty.
But the result was that it always returns true, becouse it not check each one of the properties.
So, I tried to call method validateProperty several-times, each time for other field of the complexType. It give me boolian-result of valid/not valid, but not update the validation-errors.

Here is the code that I tried after I saw Jay answer, but it is not help:

```
  validateSingleField(myComplexProertyName);
```

**first version of validateSingleField function: (the result was that it always returns true, becouse it not check each one of the properties)**

```
 function validateSingleField(object, fieldName) {     
    var entityAspect = object.entityAspect;
    var objectType = object.entityType;
    var prop = objectType.getProperty(fieldName);
            
    var value = object.getProperty(fieldName);
    if (prop.validators.length > 0) {
        var context = { entity: entityAspect.entity, property: prop, propertyName: fieldName };
        if (entityAspect._validateProperty(value, context)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**second version:(It give me boolian-result of valid/not valid, but not update the validation-errors.)**

```
 function validateSingleField(object, fieldName) {
    var aspect = object.entityAspect || object.complexAspect;
    var entityAspect = object.entityAspect || object.complexAspect.getEntityAspect();
    var objectType = object.entityType || object.complexType;
    var prop = objectType.getProperty(fieldName);
    if (prop.isComplexProperty) {
        var isOk;
        objectType.getProperties().forEach(function (p) {               
            isOk = isOk && validateSingleField(object[fieldName](), p.name)//writing 'object[fieldName]()' - is for send the entire complexType of the entity 
        });
        return isOk;              
    }
    else {
        {
            var value = object.getProperty(fieldName);
            if (prop.validators.length > 0) {
                var context = { entity: entityAspect.entity, property: prop, propertyName: fieldName };
                if (entityAspect._validateProperty(value, context)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate method to validate a complex type because the validation results are all part of the 'parent' entity.  Complex type properties are considered part of the entity, not independent entities.

What you can do is call *validateProperty* on the 'complex' property of the parent entity.

Comment: I tried it and it return 'true' even that the complexType is not valid. It didn't check each one of its properties. I tried also use 'validateProperty' for each one of the properties of the complexType, but- it didn't give me validationErrors, it only told that the property is not valid.

Comment: I edited my question following your answer. Can you read it again and try answer me?

Comment: I found the way. Thank you